# SQL SERVER MIN AND MAX DATES PER CLIENT ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query to show the earliest and latest dates(Max(FROMDATE) and Min(FROMDATE) per account opened for a client, .i.e., Number of accounts that exist for a certain client on a particular date. I seem to be getting the same values for min and max dates.

See the code below; These are made up table names for the purpose of the question.

```
<SELECT DISTINCT 
c.COLUMNNAME
,a.COLUMNNAME
,CASE 
WHEN d.product IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6')
THEN 'Products'
ELSE 'Other'
END AS PRODUCT_GROUP
,c.FROMDATE
,min(cast(c.FROMDATE as date)) AS MIN_DAT
,max(cast(c.FROMDATE as date)) AS MAX_DAT
FROM tablename a
left outer JOIN tablename b ON a.id = b.Id AND b.date = '9999-12-31'
left outer JOIN tablename c ON a.number = c.number
left outer JOIN tablenameT d ON d.code = c.code
WHERE c.FROMDATE between '20180601'and '20180830' and a.DATE ='99991231'
group by 
c.COLUMNNAME
,a.COLUMNNAME
,CASE 
WHEN d.product IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6')
THEN 'Products'
ELSE 'Other'
END
,c.FROMDATE>
```

Comment: It's likely your grouping logic is giving you extra rows and causing the dates to be the same, break down your query to the simplest query to give you the dates to perform the min/max operations and it should work. Then build up your query slowly to see what is causing the query output to change.

Comment: Thanks Tanner.I have tried that already and changed the logic several times. also re written the query line by line but i get the same results still.Do you see anything wrong with my grouping logic..something i might have missed? Let me try again.Thanks for your Input Tanner.

Comment: `GROUP BY ... ,c.FROMDATE` <<<

Comment: Ivan spotted your issue, you need to remove c.FROMDATE from both your select and group by.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you almost never should be using `SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`.  This is suspicious.

Second, you have `MIN(FROMDATE)` and `MAX(FROMDATE)` in the `SELECT` list, but you also have `FROMDATE` in the `GROUP BY`.  That is probably your major problem.

```
SELECT c.COLUMNNAME, a.COLUMNNAME,
       (CASE WHEN d.product IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6') -- do not use single quotes if these are numbers
             THEN 'Products'
             ELSE 'Other'
        END) AS PRODUCT_GROUP,
       MIN(CAST(c.FROMDATE as date)) AS MIN_DAT,
       MIN(CAST(c.FROMDATE as date)) AS MAX_DAT
FROM tablename a LEFT JOIN
     tablename b
     ON a.id = b.Id AND b.date = '9999-12-31' LEFT JOIN
     tablename c
     ON a.number = c.number LEFT JOIN
     tablenameT d
     ON d.code = c.code
WHERE c.FROMDATE between '20180601' and '20180830' and
      a.DATE = '99991231'
GROUP BY c.COLUMNNAME, a.COLUMNNAME,
        (CASE WHEN d.product IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6') -- do not use single quotes if these are numbers
              THEN 'Products'
              ELSE 'Other'
         END);
```

If you want the *number of accounts* as well, then I would expect a `COUNT(*)` or something like that in the query.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for your inputs,They have all been very valuable. I have re written the query and added most of your inputs and it works great!!!Fantastic!! Thanks Gordon!!